# Redirecting a logged-in wordpress user away from the sign-in screen and back to a specific url based on their custom metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, redirect, metadata

I currently have a solution which:
a) requires login before you can access the site
b) redirects to login page (note this is also the home page/front page) if the person attempts to hit any page in the site but is not logged in
c) directs the user on successful login to a site specific url most suitable to them based on some custom meta data in their profile

However I want to set up a further redirect should a user who is already logged-in hit the login page again and effectively achieve exactly the same re-directions as in C above.

I've attempted to utilise existing `add_login_check` code which uses `is_user_logged_in` and `wp_redirect`... but I can't seem to attach additional if and elseif statements. So something like this works great for a single redirect but I need to enhance it to cope with more conditions

```
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');

function add_login_check()
{
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(86) ) {
    wp_redirect('/desired_url');
    exit;
}
}
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

So I attempted to modify to:

```
function add_login_check()
{
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(86) && 'CustomResponse1' == 
get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'Custom_Group1', true ) && 'CustomResponse2' == 
get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'CustomGroup2', true )) {
    wp_redirect('/desired_url');
    exit;
}
}
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

I've added `&& 'CustomResponse1' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'Custom_Group1', true ) && 'CustomResponse2' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'CustomGroup2', true )` to that standard code, but when a logged-in user returns to the login page they just stay there and it does not redirect.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. In the above my users have two additional fields (I've referred to CustomGroups 1 & 2). And then there are selections which can be made in those fields (I've referred to CustomResponses 1 & 2) - based on these alongside the request page and current status being logged in I want them to be redirected.

I want to build in some additonal elseif statements so the redirects are dependent on different customresponses.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution used in the end

```
function redirect_my_page()
{
global $current_user;
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(86) && 'CustomResponse1' == get_user_meta( $user- 
>ID, 'CustomGroup1', true ) && 'CustomResponse2' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 
'CustomGroup2', true ))
{
wp_redirect('http://desiredurl/');
exit;
}
elseif ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(86) && 'CustomResponse1a' == get_user_meta( 
$user->ID, 'CustomResponse1', true ) && 'CustomResponse2a' == get_user_meta( $user- 
>ID, 'CustomResponse2', true ))
{
wp_redirect('http://desiredurl/');
exit;
}
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_my_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a undefined variable `$user`. Use [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) function to retrieve the current user object.

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    { 
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( is_page(86) && 
             'CustomResponse1' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'Custom_Group1', true ) && 
             'CustomResponse2' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'CustomGroup2', true )) 
        {
            wp_redirect('/desired_url');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi NMR, thank you for the input, it was a long week. I did struggle with this exact code to get the desired result. However you put me on the straight and narrow. I'll post the final piece of code I used for anyone else looking for a similar solution. Cheers.